# Complex symplectic group and geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

This question is somewhat silly; I'm a bit confused and asking for clarification. A symplectic manifold is a (real) manifold equipped with a closed non-degenerate 2-form, or equivalently an integrable $\text{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{R})$-structure. The group $\text{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{R})$ is defined as the group of linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus \mathbb{R}^n$ which preserve the standard symplectic form

$$ \omega = dx_1 \wedge dy_1 + \cdots + dx_n \wedge dy_n $$

There also exists the group $\text{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{C})$, and that's the one I'm a bit confused about. As far as I can see, it seems to be again defined as the group of linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n \oplus \mathbb{C}^n$ preserving a form defined by the same formula as above, but [apparently it might not?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix#Complex_matrices)

Furthermore, I'm curious as to the geometrical significance of this complex symplectic group. For example, do people study manifolds equipped with integrable $\text{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{C})$-structures? Those would need to have real dimension $4n$, I suppose. My first instinct was to guess such a thing would be a symplectic structure plus a compatible complex structure -- but there's no reason for such things to require real dimension a multiple of $4$, is there? I don't really understand what's going on here, as I think I've never heard of using this group to do symplectic geometry.

Comment: People do study symplectic algebraic geometry, so symplectic varieties and so forth. You can try looking up "holomorphic symplectic geometry."